# passportjs error callback throwing exception

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm using LocalStrategy with MYSQL(with sequelize) which is working except when MYSQL throws exception (just to test, I shut down MYSQL server). The `return done(error)` callback throwing exception crashing server.

Here is my piece of code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password'},
    function (email, password, done) {
        db.User.find({where: {email: email}}).done(function (error, user) {
            if(error) return done(error);

            if (!user) return done(null, false, {message: 'unknown user'});

            //validate password
            if (user.password != password) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'invalid password'});
            }
            //all ok
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

And the exception:

```
TypeError: Property 'next' of object #<Context> is not a function
    at Context.actions.error
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
    req._passport.instance.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) return validator.emit('exception', err);

        if (!user) {
            validator.result.errors.push('Username and password combination not found.');
            validator.emit('response');
        } else {
            req.login(user, function (error) {
                if (error) return validator.emit('exception', error);

                validator.emit('response');
            });
        }
    })(req, res);
```

Comment: Could you show how you're using `passport.authenticate` in your routes?

Comment: I've added `authenticate` code

Comment: That looks rather hackish, and might be the cause of your problems. Take a look at [this page](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), the part about *"Custom Callbacks"*; it uses `passport.authenticate` instead of using `req._passport.instance.authenticate`.

Comment: Never mind, that's not causing the issue I think (tried it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK silly me, I missed the `next` at the end

```
req._passport.instance.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
.....
})(req, res, next);
```